# How to ensure valid type conversion of a native DLL method output when DLL is loaded dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, dll

I need to load/unload an "unmanaged" third party DLL within a C# program to ensure DLL reference count is properly resetted at some point. This DLL has a (native) method to generate files and this method returns a numeric output code depending on the operation status (0,...3,100,...).

I may have missed something but when loaded this DLL "dynamically" with LoadLibrary (kernel32.dll method), and unloaded with FreeLibrary (kernel32.dll method), I can't get the desired output codes, even if the native DLL method does its job (properly generating file).

I suspect that there might be an issue with my second implementation regarding native output type conversion, what did I misundertood or missed?

**1 ) ImportDLL**

Native DLL method return code: 0

```
class Program
{    
   [DllImport(@"C:\Windows\System32\mythirdpartydll.dll")] 
    private static extern int nativeDLLMethod(string _filename, out int _returncode);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int _returncode;
        _returncode = nativeDLLMethod(_filepath, out _returncode);
        // Output
        Console.WriteLine("Native DLL method return code: " + _returncode)
    }
}
```

**2 ) LoadLibrary/UnloadLibrary**

Native DLL method return code: -2147418113

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string _dllpath);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr _module, string _function);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr _module);
}

class Program
{
    UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private delegate int nativeDLLMethod(string _filename);
    static nativeDLLMethod _nativedllmethod;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr _dllpointer = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"C:\Windows\System32\mythirdpartydll.dll");
        IntPtr _ddlmethodpointer = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(_dllpointer, "nativeDLLMethod");

        _nativedllmethod = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<nativeDLLMethod>(_ddlmethodpointer);

        _resultcode = _nativedllmethod(_filepath);

        // Output
        Console.WriteLine("Native DLL method return code: " + _returncode)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `DllImport`ed function has two parameters, your `nativeDLLMethod` delegate has one.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @GSerg. But how should I get the return code then?  _resultcode = _nativedllmethod(_filepath, out _resultcode) yield an error in VS "argument 2 may not be passed with out keyword"

Comment: Did you declare the second parameter as `out` in the delegate as well?

Comment: @GSerg nope, you're correct. result code is now properly returned. Thanks!